# Continuous function f such that its inverse takes exactly two values in R except at three points.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to [1,3]$ be a continuous function such that $f^{-1}(1)$ and $f^{-1}(3)$ are singletons  and $f^{-1}(x)$  consists of exactly two real numbers $\forall x\in (1,2) \cup (2,3)$.Then prove that the cardinality  of $f^{-1}(2)$ is either 1 or uncountable.
I am able to define a function $f(x)$ for the case when $f^{-1}(2)$ is uncountable as shown below :
Let $A(-3,2)\,,B(-2,3)\,,C(1,1)\,,D(3,2)$ be four points. 
The function $f(x)=\begin{cases}
2&,x\le -3 \\
\text{line}\,\, AB&,-3\le x \le -2\\
\text{line}\,\, BC&,-2\le x \le 1\\
\text{line} \,\,CD&,1\le x \le 3\\
2&,x\ge 3
\end{cases}$\
For the function $f$, the pre image of 2 is uncountable.
I am not able to draw a graph for the case $f^{-1}(2)$ is singleton.Help please.And how do we prove the two cases analytically ? Thank you for the help.

Comment: MathJax is not TeX.  pstricks does not work here.  To include a picture, you will need to render it in a useful format, such as .png or .jpg, then upload it and link it.  The uploading and linking can be handled by the SE software, using the little button with a picture on it in the edit dialog.  I would strongly recommend that you delete your post until you get it into a reasonable state, lest it earn downvotes for the poor formatting.

Comment: Also, I'm nearly 100% sure this is a dupe

Comment: Problem corrected and posted in new format.

Answer (score -2):

For the case $f^{-1}(2)$ singleton you could create a graph that goes:

as $x \to -\infty$, $f(x) \to 2+$

as $x \to +\infty$, $f(x) \to 2-$

$f(-1) = 3$

$f(1) = 1$

$f(0) = 2$

and then join it up with a smooth line. As $x$ increases, it goes up from just above $2$ till $3$, then it goes down through $2$ to $1$, and then goes up again slowly till just below $2$.

Is that the sort of thing you had in mind?

Comment: This is handwaving at best.

Comment: Let me delete the problem and post it in correct format.

Comment: Of course it's handwaving. It's up to OP to do the work to finish it off.

Comment: I am unable to delete the problem. Can anyone guide me to delete please.

Comment: I request the admin to delete the problem as I am unable to do it.

Comment: Why is this post being downvoted so heavily? It does what was requested -- the question went "I am not able to draw a graph for the case $f^{-1} (2)$ singleton." All I wanted to do was to demonstrate that such a graph exists. There was never an attempt to actually define one mathematically. Perhaps I ought to just randomly mark down everything *I* see that I don't understand.